# Let $L/Q$ be a field extension. Let $\sigma\in\textrm{Aut}_Q(L)$. Let $f(x) \in Q[x]$ be a polynomial. Show that $f(σ(α)) = σ(f(α))$ for all $α ∈ L.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $L/Q$ be a field extension. Let $\sigma\in\textrm{Aut}_Q(L)$. Let $f(x) \in Q[x]$ be a polynomial. Show that $f(σ(α)) = σ(f(α))$ for all $α ∈ L.$

The statement is obviously true for $α ∈ Q$ because $\text{Aut}_Q(L)$ fixes $Q$. However, I don't know how to extend the conclusion to other elements in $L$.

Comment: Extend it to monomials and then to $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0$.

Comment: You may try first with $f(x) = 2 x^2+1$

Comment: Start from the R.H.S.- use the fact that $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(x)\sigma(y)$ and $\sigma(x+y)=\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)$- then, finally, use the fact that $\sigma$ fixes $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ with $n\in\Bbb N$ and $a_i\in Q$.
Then for every $\alpha\in L$ we have
\begin{align}
\sigma(f(\alpha))
&=\sigma\left(\sum_{i=0}^na_i\alpha^i\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\sigma(\alpha)^i\\
&=f(\sigma(\alpha))
\end{align}

Comment: Beautiful proof! Thanks so much!